# Change port binding from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 on Oracle Linux 6 (RHEL 6)

Tags: rhel, firewall, oracle-linux

I need to expose my Rails port, which is port 3000.

I can see from `netstat -ntlp` that it is set up for only the local machine's users, i.e. `127.0.0.1`. I need to change this to `0.0.0.0` but I am not sure how to do so.